# Regex matching entire string

Tags: java, regex

How can I make my string only pass a test if every character in the string is in the regex?

Here is what I have so far:

```
String w = theApplet.Word.getText().toLowerCase();
if(w.matches(".*[a-z-_]+.*")){
    theApplet.words.add(w);
    theApplet.str.setText("The word: "+w+" has been added to the list");
}
```

However, the string is valid even if it contains invalid characters, as long as it contains at least 1 of the characters in the regex.

Comment: How about `if(w.matches("[a-z-_]+"))`?

Comment: that's what `.*` means in your regex. I assume you can probably just remove those

Comment: `.` matches any character, unless you escape it with `/`, and you're worsening the problem with the `*`, which means `any number of times` )for the previous "any character" `.`).

Comment: @TheLima You probably meant ``\`` (to write it in comment use `\`\\`\`)

Comment: @Pshemo Oh, you're right...Got my slashes switched up there, sorry...00:38 oclock here, and no coffee...I have pizza and coke though. =)

Comment: OP, are upper-case characters valid, by any chance? Or just lower-case? Solution might be simpler depending if it's allowed to have uppers.

Comment: he toLowerCase()'s it at the beginning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.*` means "match any character zero or more times"

`[a-z-_]+` means "match any lowercase character or dash (-) or underscore (_) one or more times".

So the first part is consuming nearly the entire string and the regex is returning true if there is at least one lowercase character/dash/underscore.

Simply remove the `.*`'s to force all characters to be lowercase characters/dashes/underscores.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, this and Pshemo's work perfectly.